# Fail to import gdal from conda environment?

Tags: python, gdal, anaconda

I installed gdal from this link:
http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-3-0-0-mapserver-7-4-0.zip
When I use the the following command from this environment and location:

**(base) C:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah>**from osgeo import gdal
it gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init__.py", line 21, in 
>       _gdal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

But it successfully import if I use the following location:
**(base) C:\Program Files\GDAL>**from osgeo import gdal

How can I solve this issue? I want to use the first location for my conda environment.

Comment: I believe the most straightforward way to install `gdal` having Anaconda its just running `conda install gdal` in your environment.

Comment: @Marcelo Villa  thanks for your comment. I tried using conda but failed.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: Create a fresh environment then install from conda-forge with `conda install gdal -c conda-forge`

Comment: @mikewatt thanks for your comment. How can I create a fresh environment?

Comment: [`conda create -n environmentname python=3.6`](http://know.continuum.io/rs/387-XNW-688/images/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) then run the above

Comment: @mikewatt that means you suggest me to create new environment?

Comment: @mikewatt thanks, after uninstalling old gdal and reinstalling using conda, problem solved. But still now make me confusion about my previous error.

Comment: did you install the osgeo stuff inside your conda env? If you just used the installer you linked in the first post, it is installed on your system but not known to your conda environment.

Comment: @zwnk after uninstalling old gdal and reinstalling using conda, problem is solved.  >>it is installed on your system but not known to your conda environment-- I agree with you